Does 'friendship' collocate with make?
One of my students wrote in a text "I made a friendship with you."
That sounds odd to me. However, on ozdic.com it says that friendship would collocate with 'make.' My google search didn't get me any further, since the results seemed to be all about 'making friendship bracelets'.
Would be grateful for help.
Best,
Kathrin


We make many friendships in school. Sometimes we have these friendships all our lives.

Did you make any friends at school?
BUT NOT: I made a friendship with you.
But we do say: I made friends with you. OR I made you my friend. OR I made a friend of you.


In conclusion: we make friends, we make friendships, but not make friendship with you, them etc. It's awkward and unidiomatic.

Our friendship lasted for 20 years.


Thank you for the examples!

While it is completely understandable, it doesn't colocate well.  The usual expression is "I made friends with you".

Thank you for your comment. 'Make friends' is indeed very common.
